# Let $a, b\in G$ be, where $G$ is a finite group. If $G=[a]=[b]$, prove then $a$ and $b$ has the same order

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

**Edited:** Let's suppose that $o(a)=p$ and $o(b)=q$. For every $x\in G$, we can find $m, n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x=a^m=b^n$. So,

$$x^p=(b^n)^p=(a^m)^p=(a^p)^m=e^m=e \Rightarrow q\mid p,$$
$$x^q=(a^m)^q=(b^n)^q=(a^q)^n=e^n=e \Rightarrow p\mid q.$$

Hence $p=q$.

Another I thought is to prove that $f:[a] \rightarrow [b] $ defined by $f(a^k) =b^k$ is an isomorphism. In fact, $f$ is $1-1$ because

$$f(a^{k_1})=f(a^{k_2}) \Rightarrow b^{k_1}=b^{k_2} \Rightarrow k_1=k_2.$$

Taking $x\in B$, then $x=b^i$, for some $i\in\mathbb{Z}$ and we can write $x=b^i=f(a^i)$. Since $a^i\in[a]$, $f$ is onto. Finally, if $a^m,a^n\in[a]$, we get

$$f(a^ma^n)=f(a^{m+n}) =b^{m+n}=b^mb^n=f(a^m)f(b^n).$$

$[a]$ and $[b]$ are finite and isomorphism. Hence they have the same order.

Do you agree with me?

Comment: In the first sequence of equalities, why do you assert that $a^{h_1}=e$? Besides, it is false that $b^{k_1}=b^{k_2}\implies k_1=k_2$.

Comment: If $[a]$ means the subgroup generated by $a$, then this seems a triviality, since the order of an element is (almost by definition) the number of elements in the subgroup it generates. The elements $a$ and  $b$ just lead to two different ways of enumerating the elements of the group $G$; by kindergarten combinatorics, the number of elements of a set does not depend on the the order in which one enumerates.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I have rewritten my 1st argument because those $h_1$ and $h_2$ had nothing to do

Comment: Why does it follow from $x^p=e$ that $q\mid p$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos you're right. There is no sense. Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach is wrong because you cannot deduce from the fact that $x^p=e$ that $q\mid p$. The second approach is also wrong because it doesn't follow from $b^{k_1}=b^{k_2}$ that $k_1=k_2$,

If $G=[a]$, then $o(a)=\#G$. Therefore, if $G=[a]=[b]$, then $o(a)=o(b)$ since both numbers are equal to the order of $G$.